Label switching issue about the covariance in MSVAR model
Suppose I have a simple MSVAR model with 1 lag and 2 variables and 2 regimes, where VAR term is regime-independent:
Regime 1:
$$y^{1}_t = y^1_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,1} + y^{2}_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,2} + \gamma_{1,1}$$
$$y^{2}_t = y^{1}_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,1} + y^{2}_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,2} + \gamma_{1,2}$$
Covariance 1: $\Sigma^1=
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma^1_{11} & \Sigma^1_{12} \\
\Sigma^1_{21} & \Sigma^1_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}  $
Regime 2:
$$y^1_t = y^1_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,1} + y^{2}_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,2} + \gamma_{2,1}$$
$$y^2_t = y^1_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,1} + y^{2}_{t-1} \cdot \gamma_{0,2} + \gamma_{2,2}$$
Covariance 2: $\Sigma^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma^2_{11} & \Sigma^2_{12} \\
\Sigma^2_{21} & \Sigma^2_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}  $
Since regime 1 is I assume to be recession and regime 2 is expansion, by their definition the restriction should be $\gamma_{1,1} < \gamma_{2,1}$ and $\gamma_{1,2} < \gamma_{2,2}$, I think it is called total ordering?.
It is possible that when label switching happens, $\gamma_{1,1}$ , $\gamma_{2,1}$, and $\gamma_{1,2}$ ,$\gamma_{2,2}$ may switch within one iteration.
My question is that, if both of $\gamma_{1,1}$ , $\gamma_{2,1}$, and $\gamma_{1,2}$, $\gamma_{2,2}$ are switched, I should swap $\Sigma^1$ and $\Sigma^2$ completely, this is easy.
However, I found that it is also possible that only one pair is switched, such as:
Regime 1:
\begin{align}
y^1_t & = \text{lag_term}  + “\boldsymbol{\gamma_{2,1}}” \\
y^2_t & = \text{lag_term} + \gamma_{1,2}
\end{align}
Regime 2:
\begin{align}
y^1_t & = \text{lag_term} + “\boldsymbol{\gamma_{1,1}}” \\
y^2_t & = \text{lag_term} + \gamma_{2,2}
\end{align}
for example, $\gamma_{1,1} > \gamma_{2,1}$ and $\gamma_{1,2} < \gamma_{2,2}$, in this case, I think I should swap the element $\Sigma^1_{11}$ and $\Sigma^2_{11}$, but I'm not sure about the off-diagonal elements in the covariance matrices, what should I do with $\Sigma^1_{12},  \Sigma^1_{21}, \Sigma^2_{12},  \Sigma^2_{21}$?
BTW, in practice, I think maybe I can simply drop all iterations in any chains which violates my total ordering? Or, I can discard iterations which has conflict b/w variables. By doing so, I can be easier to implement DIC which relies on posterior means?

I changed $\cdots+"\boldsymbol{\gamma_{1,1}}"$ to $\cdots + “\boldsymbol{\gamma_{1,1}}”.$ I assume you noticed that in MathJax (i.e. the typesetting software that is used here) you cannot code quotation marks in the way in which it is done in standard LaTeX. But you can do the following: first type &ldquo; &rdquo;, NOT in MathJax code. This will get rendered as left and right quotation marks, looking as usual like 66 and 99. Then you can copy them and paste them into your MathJax code. This won't work in standard LaTeX, but it works here with MathJax.

Yes, you are absolutely correct, thanks for your editing

I added $t$ indices to the lhs of the equations as well.
